# Can you easily simplify large exponents without Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am asked to check if $x = 19$ is a solution to the following congruence:

$$ x^{30034} ≡ 2 \pmod{18}$$

How can I do this? And in general, is there an easy/fast way to solve these types of problems when you can't use Fermat's LT?

Comment: To answer your question, in general I do not think it would be easy to simplify large exponents. It seems to be related to the [discrete log problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). The discrete log problem is solving $k$ for the equation $a^k \equiv b \bmod n$, given that such a $k$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $19\equiv 1\pmod{18}$, so it clearly is not a root of this equation.

You can show that this equation has no solutions since $y^2\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ has no solution, and $x^{30034}$ is a perfect square.

Comment: How can you show that 19≡1(mod18) --> x^30034≡2(mod18)? Also is there a rule that says: (n+a)^k ≡ a (mod n)? Because it seems to work with n=19, a=1, and k=any integer.

Comment: @AliMustafa You can use the binomial theorem,only the last term isn't a multiple of $n$

Comment: You can't show $x^{30034}\equiv 2$, because it is not true. $(n+a)^k\equiv a^k\pmod n$. As kingW3 says, that follows from the binomial theorem, or by induction on $k$. @AliMustafa